# Can I make the background of a div a clickable link?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a timeline, and I want the background fields of certain divs to take users to pages related to the topic the div contains. I was able to do this by adding an a tag to the div and styling it with CSS. Only problem was if I do it that way, I can't have links within that div work, as the div's clickability is always on top of the p and other a tags, even if I change the z index.

Is there any way to change this so that if the user clicks the div's background, but not text elements, they get taken to page A, but links within the div work normally?

```css
  div.timelinecontent a {
       z-index: 11;
  }

  div.timelinecontent a.bglink {
       position: absolute;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       text-decoration: none; /* No underlines on the link */
       z-index: 10; /* Places the link above everything else in the div */
       background-color: #FFF; /* Fix to make div clickable in IE */
       opacity: 0; /* Fix to make div clickable in IE */
       filter: alpha(opacity=1); /* Fix to make div clickable in IE */
   }
   .timelinecontent:hover{
    background-color:rgba(121, 225, 246, 0.42);
  }
```

```html
<div class="timelinecontent">
   <a class="bglink" href="http://www.example.com"></a>
     <h5>What Is Lorem Ipsum?</h5>
        <p>
          <a href="http://www.google.com">Lorem Ipsum</a> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
        </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent the event (redirect) of all links and check if the link (div) has another internal link. If it has another link, redirect to internal link else redirect to original (div) link.

```
let links = document.querySelectorAll(".timelinecontent a");
for (let link of links){
    link.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        //prevent redirect
        event.preventDefault();
        //if link contains another link
        if (link.querySelector("a"){
            //rediirect to internal link
            window.location.href = link.querySelector("a").href;
        } else {
            //else redirect to original link
            window.location.href = link.href;
        }
    })
}
```

A bit more explanation then.

`let links = document.querySelectorAll(".timelinecontent a");`

`let links` selects all links within the div with the class name `timelinecontent`.

`link.addEventListener("click", (event) => {`

then we add a click event listener to each `link`

`event.preventDefault();`

and prevents the redirect (event).

`if (link.querySelector("a"){`

Then we check if this link contains another link (anywhere as it's child)

If the link contains another link within it's hierarchy, then we get the url of the internal link and redirect the user / open in a new tab  (`window.location.href = link.querySelector("a").href;`).

`else {`

otherwise we use the already existing link to redirect (`window.location.href = link.href;.`)

Comment: I'm new to web design and JS... This looks like it would redirect all internal links to the same page, not different pages. I want links within the p tag to take users to wiki entries on specific topics while the link on the div itself takes them to a more detailed article on what the timeline summarizes. So I need a's in the p to work normally, like a stock a tag, and the div's background but not foreground to act as a link to individual pages as well.

Comment: Added an explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the explenation, I'll give this a shot!